# An equicontinous headache (problem)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

There's this family of functions: 
$$\mathcal H=\{ f_k\in\mathcal C^0([-1,1],\Bbb R) : f_k (x)=\begin{cases} -1 \;\text{if $x\in[-1,-\frac1k]$} \\ kx \;\text{if $x\in[-\frac1k,\frac1k]$} \\ 1 \;\text{if $x\in[\frac1k,1]$}\end{cases} \text{with $k\in\Bbb N$} \}$$
We have to show that $\mathcal H$ is not equicontinous in $0$.
What I've donde is this: let $\varepsilon=\frac12>0$. For any $\delta>0$ exists a $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $[-\frac1k,\frac1k]\in(-\delta,\delta)$, ie, $\frac1k=|\frac1k|<\delta$, so for the same $k$, there's a $f_k\in\mathcal H$, such that $|f_k(\frac1k)|=1>\frac12=\varepsilon$.

However I don't feel this is totally correct, so I tried looking at other properties of the functions, and I got that: if $m,n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\le m$ then $d_{\infty}(f_n,f_m)=\max_{x\in[-1,1]} |f_m(x)-f_n(x)|=|1-f_n(\frac1m)|=|1-n\frac1m|=|\frac{m-n}m|$, but this seems pointless. What am I doing wrong? This problem seems very innocous, I don't understand why I can't get it...

Comment: Your first one is spot-on.

Comment: @DanielFischer ("spot-on" means "right", right?) really? I felt uneasy because I thougt that you were supposed to take every $|x|<\delta$ and not just one type of elements, like I did.

Comment: Right, spot-on means right. You have found one $\varepsilon > 0$, so that for all $\delta > 0$, there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and an $x$ with $\lvert x-0\rvert < \delta$, and $\lvert f_k(x) - f_k(0)\rvert > \varepsilon$. That means the family is _not_ equicontinuous in $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer well I see that I didn't negate well the definition then. Thank you very much, good sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a difference of $1$ on an arbitrarily small interval for one of the functions in the sequence. This violates equicontinuity.

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting "You can find a difference of 1..." what do you mean?

Comment: Observe at $|f_k(-1/k) - f_k(1/k)|= 2$.  Notice that the points we evaluate at become arbitrarily close whilst the difference remains at 2.